# Distribute Conjugate over expression?

Tags: complex, output

I have this output:

```
Conjugate[Subscript[a, 0][x] + t^β Subscript[a, 1][x]]
```

I want to distribute `Conjugate`:

```
Conjugate[Subscript[a, 0][x]] + t^β Conjugate[Subscript[a, 1][x]]
```

I tried using `Thread[U, Plus]`, for `U` set to:

```
Conjugate[
 E^(I x) + (t^α Subscript[a, 0][x])/Gamma[1 + α] + (
  4^-α Sqrt[π] t^(2 α) Subscript[a, 1][x])/
  Gamma[1/2 + α]]
```

However, this doesn't appear to work. Any suggestion?

Comment: The result you're looking for requires the assumption that `t^\[Beta]` is real. Apart from pulling that out, a start might be `Thread[expr, Plus]`.

Comment: Many thanks. I want introduce t^\[Beta] is real in global, but I don not know. Please help abut this problem.

Comment: About 3 term, I think 'Plus' is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better option, but you can do it manually. To distribute `Conjugate` over addition, you can use `Thread` as I mentioned in the question. The reason why it doesn't work with more complicated expressions as your first example is that it's only applied at the top level. This can be fixed with replacement rule:

```
expr = Conjugate[
     E^(I x) + (t^α Subscript[a, 0][x])/Gamma[1 + α] + (
      4^-α Sqrt[π] t^(2 α) Subscript[a, 1][x])/
      Gamma[1/2 + α]]

expr /. e : Conjugate[Plus[__]] :> Thread[e, Plus]

(* E^(-I Conjugate[x]) + (
 4^-Conjugate[α] Sqrt[π]
   Conjugate[t^(2 α) Subscript[a, 1][x]])/
 Gamma[1/2 + Conjugate[α]] + 
 Conjugate[t^α Subscript[a, 0][x]]/
 Gamma[1 + Conjugate[α]] *)
```

This already gets you a good part of the way. But it doesn't pull out your prefactors yet, and neither will `Simplify`. The reason for that is the Mathematica doesn't know they are real. You can convince it that they are by giving it a suitable list of assumptions. The simplest case would be `Element[x, Reals]` for every single prefactor you have, but that could be annoying because you seem to have various combinations of `t`  and `α`. It might be better to give it a handful of more basic assumptions that guarantee that all of your prefactors will still be real, for instance:

```
Assuming[{Element[α, Reals], t > 0},
 Simplify[expr /. e : Conjugate[Plus[__]] :> Thread[e, Plus]]
]

(* E^(-I Conjugate[x]) + (
 4^-α Sqrt[π] t^(2 α)
   Conjugate[Subscript[a, 1][x]])/Gamma[1/2 + α] + (
 t^α Conjugate[Subscript[a, 0][x]])/Gamma[1 + α] *)
```

Here's a screenshot of all three expressions for better readability:

[image]

It *is* a bit odd that Mathematica distributes `Conjugate` over the exponential summand automatically, but not over the other two. If someone could shed some additional light on why that happens, I'd also be very interested.